# How to use remove element from Dictionary with lock statement for custom class?

Tags: c#, collections, signalr

I need to remove element using ContainsKey using lock.

Class:

```
   public class ConnectionMapping<T>
   {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =
            new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

        public void Remove(T key, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (_connections)
            {
                HashSet<string> connections;
                if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
                {
                    return;
                }

                lock (connections)
                {
                    connections.Remove(connectionId);

                    if (connections.Count == 0)
                        _connections.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }     
    }
```

Init

```
readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = new ConnectionMapping<string>();
```

**UPDATED**

Another class

```
public class myHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = 
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();
    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        string name = userName;  
        _connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        //_connections.Remove(Context.ConnectionId); <-- I need
    }
```

**UPDATED**
Full code:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization#authoptions

I can remove element using `_connections.Remove(Key, connectionId)`
Bit I need to use `_connections.Remove(connectionId)` How to modify the class?

Comment: What is the point of `lock (connections)`? Its a locally scoped variable.

Comment: @BradM when `TryGetValue` succeeds, it becomes a reference to a value in the `HashSet<string>` part of the SHARED private variable, and not thread safe.

Comment: I don't understand OPs question: can you be more specific or detailed?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be glaring issues - can you please clarify  your question.

Comment: updated, is it clear now?

Comment: Yes. You need to "denormalize" and have another dictionary in your connections class whose key is the connection ID and value(s) is/are the names. Then you need to keep those two dictionaries in sync.

Comment: What about ContainsKey ? Is it right to use it in this case?

Comment: I don't see how `ContainsKey` would be useful here.

Comment: @DavidHaney post an example please. I will mark your answer.

Comment: why not get the key from the connectionId, then proceed with your current code `var key = _connections.Where(pair => pair.Value.Contains(connectionId)).Select(pair => pair.Key).SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a **Dictionary**, Use a **ConcurrentDictionary**